# Dual boot installation

Tags: linux, windows-10, operating-systems, windows-installation, dualboot

I recently bought Lenovo L340 with 1TB HDD + 256GB SSD with windows 10 home pre-installed on SSD. I wanted to install Linux Kali alongside it and was wondering if it'd be okay to install Linux on SSD and windows on HDD. Would it work properly? If not, what combination should I go for?

Comment: Kali isn't meant to be installed. It's also not intended to be used as a general-purpose Linux distribution. If you have to ask this question, you should just use Kali as intended: by live booting it or in a VM. [Please read this](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me). If you want to learn more about Linux and gain some experience, I'd recommend starting with Ubuntu or its derivatives.

Comment: Actually I'm quite comfortable using Kali Linux and have been using it on the other laptop that I have. Since I'm wanting to install it on the new laptop, I was wondering if the setup I'm thinking of would work properly. You see, if I install windows 10 on HDD, the MBR will be on HDD only and GRUB will be installed on SSD. Will GRUB then be able to detect windows on HDD for dual boot or will I have to choose the hard drive to boot from BIOS? @gronostaj

Comment: You're either already using UEFI boot or should consider it, because it's the default method since 10 years or so. Unlike BIOS boot it doesn't rely on MBR, but on bootloaders stored on EFI System Partition (ESP). You can have multiple ESPs and UEFI (successor of BIOS) will recognize all of them. So you can contain each OS to a single disk, including all its boot stuff, and make both OSes independent from other disks. I'm not sure if GRUB will like it, but I'd guess it will. There are also alternatives such as rEFInd (install-and-forget kind of thing) and systemd-boot (some effort required).

Comment: Ah! Okay, and, yep, I'm already using UEFI, but was wondering if I reinstalled windows and Linux on separate disks with underlying UEFI boot, would it cause any problems. But now I have a clarity after reading on how to manage it. Thanks :)